# How do I get the Enemy to pickup the closet weapon after running out of ammo?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an enemy that is 'smart', that changes a weapon if it has no ammo left and if all its weapons are depleted of ammo find the nearest weapon and change the weapon.

So far, I have an enemy that can patrol, find player in range, chase and attack the player.

Here is the code:

```
public class EnemyControler : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Attack")]
    [SerializeField] float shootingDistance =10.0f;
    [SerializeField] float shootDelay = 3.5f;
    [Range(0,1.0f)][SerializeField] float shootingAccuracy =0.5f;
    [SerializeField] int shootDamage =5;
    [SerializeField] int ammo = 1;

    [Header("User Interface")]
    public Transform canvasTr;
    public Slider Healthbar;

    [Header("Health/Damage/Death")]
    public float MaxHealth;
    public float Damage;
    public float AttackRange;
    public int deathCounter;


    public Transform ammoObject;
    private NavMeshAgent navAgent;
    private Collider enemycollider;
    private Transform PlayerTr;
    private Animator EnemyAnim;


    float Health;
    bool showingHealthBar, alive;
    bool isPatrolling =false;
    bool isInShootingRange =false;
    bool canResumeIdleState =true;
    bool isPreparingToShoot=false;
    bool isDead =false;
    bool isAlerted =false;
    float shootTimer = Mathf.Infinity;
    AIPatrolBehavior aIPatrolBehavior = null;
    
    void Start()
    {
        Health = MaxHealth;
        canvasTr.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        navAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        EnemyAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        enemycollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
        PlayerTr = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        aIPatrolBehavior = GetComponent<AIPatrolBehavior>();
        alive = true;
        ammo = 100;
        StartCoroutine(Idle());
        // are you sure you want to randomly change MaxHealth after settting health = maxHealth?
        //the slider gets weirdly bugged
        //   MaxHealth = Random.Range(50, 200); 


        Healthbar.maxValue = MaxHealth; // set the max value to MaxHelth
    }

    private void Update() 
    {   
        if(isDead)return;

        if(Vector3.Distance(PlayerTr.transform.position, transform.position) > 20 && !isAlerted
        || PlayerTr.GetComponent<PlayerController>().HealthBar.value <= 0.0f){
            StopAllCoroutines();
            GetComponent<AIPatrolBehavior>().enabled =true;
            return;
        }
        if(Vector3.Distance(PlayerTr.transform.position, transform.position) < 20 && isAlerted) isAlerted=false;
        isInShootingRange = DistanceToPlayer() < shootingDistance &&
         DistanceToPlayer() > AttackRange - 0.5f && 
         PlayerTr.GetComponent<PlayerController>().HealthBar.value > 0;




        if(isInShootingRange)
        {
            if(canResumeIdleState){
                StopAllCoroutines();
                canResumeIdleState=false;
            }
            ProcessShooting();
        }  else{

            if(!canResumeIdleState){
                isPreparingToShoot =false;
                StartCoroutine(Idle());
                canResumeIdleState =true;
                navAgent.enabled =true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessShooting()
    {
        if(!isPreparingToShoot) shootTimer +=Time.deltaTime;
        navAgent.enabled =false;
        transform.LookAt(PlayerTr);
        float randomProbability =Random.Range(0,1.0f);
        if(shootTimer > shootDelay){
            ShootAtPlayer();
        }
        EnemyAnim.SetFloat("MovmentSpeed", 0, 0.3f, Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void ShootAtPlayer(){
        if(isPreparingToShoot)return;
        EnemyAnim.SetBool("PrepareAttack", false);
        shootTimer =0.0f;
        isPreparingToShoot = true;
        EnemyAnim.SetTrigger("shoot");
    }

    public void ShootPlayerAnimationEvent(){
        Debug.Log("Player got shot");
        float randomAccuracy = Random.Range(0, 1.0f);
        bool willHitTarget = randomAccuracy > 1.0f - shootingAccuracy;
        if(willHitTarget && DistanceToPlayer() < shootingDistance){
            PlayerTr.GetComponent<PlayerController>().DoDamage(shootDamage,true);
        }
        GetComponentInChildren<AIWeapon>().UseWeapon();
        isPreparingToShoot =false;
    }

    IEnumerator Idle()
    {        
        EnemyAnim.SetBool("PrepareAttack", false);

        yield return new WaitUntil(() => Vector3.Distance(PlayerTr.transform.position, transform.position) < 20 || isAlerted);
        StartCoroutine(RunToTarget());
    }
    IEnumerator RunToTarget()
    {
        aIPatrolBehavior.enabled =false;

        if(navAgent.isOnNavMesh) { // save from error apperng
            navAgent.isStopped = false;
        }

        EnemyAnim.SetTrigger("Attack");
        while (Vector3.Distance(PlayerTr.transform.position, transform.position) > AttackRange - 0.5f)
        {
            if(navAgent.isOnNavMesh) { // save from error apperng
                navAgent.SetDestination(PlayerTr.position);
            }
            
        //    navAgent.SetDestination(PlayerTr.position);
            EnemyAnim.SetFloat("MovmentSpeed", 1, 0.3f, Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
        StartCoroutine(Attack());
    }
    IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        EnemyAnim.SetBool("PrepareAttack", true);
        navAgent.isStopped = true;
        while (Vector3.Distance(PlayerTr.position, transform.position) < AttackRange)
        {
            EnemyAnim.SetTrigger("Attack");
            float t = 0.5f;
            while (t > 0)
            {
                Vector3 rotation = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, PlayerTr.position - transform.position, 5f * Time.deltaTime, 1f);
                transform.forward = rotation;
                t -= Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
        EnemyAnim.SetBool("PrepareAttack", false);
        StartCoroutine(RunToTarget());
    }

   


    float DistanceToPlayer(){
        return Vector3.Distance(transform.position,PlayerTr.position);
    }

    public void DoDamage(float damage)
    {
        Alert();
        if (!showingHealthBar)
        {
            showingHealthBar = true;
            StartCoroutine(ShowHealthBar());
        }
        Health -= damage;
        Debug.Log("Health: " + Health + " of: " + MaxHealth);
        Healthbar.value = Health;
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            if(navAgent.isOnNavMesh) { // save from error apperng
                navAgent.isStopped = true;
            }
            if (alive)
            {
                alive = true; // does this make sense?
                StartCoroutine(Death());
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried searching through Google to find any tutorials, but without success. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfow. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. There is too much code in your question , please reduce it to a [mcve]

Comment: Tbh much in the way you would find anything in a range. Then pick the nearest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the weapons placed on constant places all over the map, you can make the enemy stop patrolling or chasing the player when his ammo == 0 by a Boolean then use `MoveTowrds()` the weapon.
and u can include some way to calculate the distance between the enemy's position and all the weapons on the array, then it head for the closest.
you will use an array of vectors to store the locations of weapons.
now its your turn to try.